# Git pre-commit hook (windows) gives No such file or directory error

Tags: bash, git, powershell, github, git-bash

I have a very simple requirement to show a pre-defined template on commit and to ensure it is not violated.

So I have done the following steps :

1. created a template message in .getmessage
2. set the commit.template to the above template

   git config --global commit.template /d/gitTest/.gitmessage   (using GitBash)
3. Verified on commit that the pre-defined template is shown.
4. Create a pre-commit hook in .git/hooks/

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the default commit message from a file
commit_msg_file="/d/gitTest/.gitmessage"
commit_msg=$(cat "$commit_msg_file")

# Prepend the default commit message to the commit message file
echo -e "$commit_msg\n$(cat "$1")" > "$1"
```

5. The directory structure (windows ) is

> ```
> D://gitTest/.git/hooks/pre-commit 
> D://gitTest/.gitmessage
> ```

But now on commit it fails with

```
$ git commit
cat: '': No such file or directory
.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 8: : No such file or directory
```

On GitBash I am able to access file as -> $ vim /d/gitTest/.gitmessage

Maybe shell or maybe path wrt Windows is causing the issue. I am not able to figure out. Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised by line 8,

```
echo -e "$commit_msg\n$(cat "$1")" > "$1"
```

`pre-commit` does not take any parameter. So, `$1` is always empty and `cat ""` raises the error.

What you need is `prepare-commit-msg`. Rename `pre-commit` to `prepare-commit-msg`.

Comment: Thank you updating in prepare-commit-msg fixed the issue.